# AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'to_bytes'

Tags: command-line, python, arduino

Iam trying to program Arduino Uno using python program. My python version is python 3.8. I successfully installed the pyfirmata2. but when i tried to import pyfirmata2 from command line iam getting the following error.

```
>>> import pyfirmata2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyfirmata2\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pyfirmata2 import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyfirmata2\pyfirmata2.py", line 7, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\serial\tools\list_ports.py", line 27, in <module>
    from serial.tools.list_ports_windows import *
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\serial\tools\list_ports_windows.py", line 127, in <module>
    Ports = serial.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 115]) # "Ports"
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'to_bytes'
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `to_bytes()` is available for `int` types.

In the code you are running, it appears `serial` is not an `int` type but a `module` which does not have the `to_bytes()` method.

You do not state which version of `pyserial` you are running, but I cannot find the line `Ports = serial.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 115]) # "Ports"` in the [current source code for that file from `pyserial`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/list_ports_windows.py).  I did find that line was removed in 2016 [with this commit](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/commit/2c84964936cdbe16c623ff874b7a528cc9d7a50d#diff-923b2645a5641c248bcc87347ed10b5266a3ecc336b62273a298514701a63b21), so maybe a newer version of `pyserial` would solve your problem?

Comment: I uninstall pyserial , serial and pyfirmata altogether and then i reinstall pyfirmata only after that the i try to import pyfirmata now its working without any error thanks for your suggestion.